# Terraform plan ask for destroy even nothing changed

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Still new to terraform here so I might be missing something basic, but all my research went out of luck. I am testing tf to deploy a aurora cluster with the following file:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "default" {
db_subnet_group_name    = aws_db_subnet_group.db_sub_group.name
cluster_identifier      = "aurora-cluster-demo"
engine                  = "aurora-postgresql"
engine_version          = "13.6"
availability_zones      = ["ca-central-1a", "ca-central-1b"]
database_name           = "mydb"
master_username         = "foo"
master_password         = "testpassword"
backup_retention_period = 5
preferred_backup_window = "07:00-09:00"
skip_final_snapshot = true
```

}

But everytime I perform an apply, it will destroy and create. I am getting the following plan:

```
aws_rds_cluster.default: Refreshing state... [id=aurora-cluster-demo]
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
   plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:

-/+ destroy and then create replacement
 Terraform will perform the following actions:
 # aws_rds_cluster.default must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_rds_cluster" "default" {
 ~ allocated_storage   = 1 -> (known after apply)
 + apply_immediately   = (known after apply)
 ~ arn = "arn:aws:rds:ca-central-1:132456:cluster:aurora-cluster-demo" -> (known after apply)
 ~ availability_zones  = [ # forces replacement
  - "ca-central-1d",
# (2 unchanged elements hidden)
 ]
 - backtrack_window = 0 -> null
 + cluster_identifier_prefix = (known after apply)
 ~ cluster_members = [] -> (known after apply)
 ~ cluster_resource_id = "cluster-xxxxx" -> (known after apply)
 ~ db_cluster_parameter_group_name = "default.aurora-postgresql13" -> (known after apply)
 - deletion_protection = false -> null
 - enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports = [] -> null
 ~ endpoint = "aurora-cluster-demo.cluster-xxxx.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply)
 ~ engine_version_actual = "13.6" -> (known after apply)
 ~ hosted_zone_id = "xxxxx" -> (known after apply)
 - iam_database_authentication_enabled = false -> null
 ~ iam_roles = [] -> (known after apply)
 ~ id = "aurora-cluster-demo" -> (known after apply)
 - iops = 0 -> null
 + kms_key_id = (known after apply)
 ~ network_type = "IPV4" -> (known after apply)
 ~ port = 5432 -> (known after apply)
 ~ preferred_maintenance_window = "fri:06:02-fri:06:32" -> (known after apply)
 ~ reader_endpoint = "aurora-cluster-demo.cluster-ro-xxxx.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply)
 ~ storage_encrypted = false -> (known after apply)
 - tags = {} -> null
 ~ tags_all {} -> (known after apply)
 ~ vpc_security_group_ids = [  - "sg-xxx",] -> (known after apply)
# (14 unchanged attributes hidden)
  }
   Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

So I see that there are some parameters in the plan are marked as changing, but I am not touching them.   Is it because they default to some value by tf internally, and then not adding make him think it is different?

Comment: The main thing is the change in availability zone. Your defining it to be in central 1a and 1b. Terraform is telling you it's also in 1d so it wants to remove this AZ it forces a replacement. Have you done anything outside of TF to deploy it into a 3rd AZ

Comment: No, I literally call the apply twice in a row in less than 30s to debug this issue. And I ca

Comment: Ok so after double checking, this was indeed the problem. Aurora will default to min 3 AZ, so by only adding two for my test, TF or AWS was filling the last one by default.

Comment: Just to add to Djoby's answer, the docs are here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster and it mentions "RDS automatically assigns 3 AZs if less than 3 AZs are configured, which will show as a difference requiring resource recreation next Terraform apply. We recommend specifying 3 AZs or using the lifecycle configuration block ignore_changes argument if necessary."